# Merging three parts of a model for eventual 3D printing

Tags: mesh, 3d-printing

I'm currently trying to take a 3d model I ripped from a video game and prep it to 3d print it for a costume's prop. My problem is that the game's model is obviously made for being virtual and not physical, so it's not all in one piece.

For some reason (I'm no game designer or modeler), the model has a lot of unattached edges. All the methods I know for merging meshes aren't working, unassumingly due to these un-closed parts. I don't even know what exactly to search for to resolve this; thus I'm coming here. I have a sculpting plugin (sculpt tools) that has a nice union option, but it's not working and causes chunks to disappear. I'm using blender 2.79

The model below, and it in its three separate pieces. You can see how there's single face parts that would connect to one if it was a solid unit:
[image: Samurai Edge(gun) 3D model]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried joining the parts into one object and removing doubles?

Comment: @HISEROD Unfortunately that still keeps all the internal parts of the mesh. Some elements that stick inside of the other pieces, which I'm pretty sure will cause issues with 3D printing, and I don't really know how to eliminate them.

Comment: You may be able to make all of the parts manifold/watertight by manually editing them and then join them with booleans.